# Prove for every $n$ belonging to $\mathbb N$ the $10^n - (-1)^n$ divisible by $11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove the subject by module-math, but I don't know how to start.
I succeed to prove it by induction method, however I want to show it with Algebra which take in account modules math.

Comment: I suppose you mean modular arithmetic. Hint: start with $10 \equiv -1 \pmod{11}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proving $11|(10^n - (-1)^n$ via modular arithmetic is to prove:

$10^n - (-1)^n \equiv 0 \pmod {11}$

which is true if and only if $10^n \equiv (-1)^n \pmod {11}$.

And as $10 = 11 - 1$ we know $10\equiv -1 \pmod {11}$ so $10^n \equiv (-1)^n \pmod{11}$.

That's all there is to it.

.......

Or if that seems too slick and unconvincing, consider:

$10^{n} = (11 - 1)^n = 11^n - n*11^{n-1} + ..... \pm n*11 + (-1)^n$

So

$10^n - (-1)^2 = 11^n - n*11^{n-1} + ...... \pm n*11$

Which is more complicated than it needs to be but that explains *why* modulo arithmetic proofs work.

Comment: Helpful! Thanks!

Comment: fleablood.10^n-(10-11)^n=(11)(......)using Foobaz hint makes the non-modulo approach a little shorter:)

Comment: Shorter.  True.  But the idea is that $10^n \equiv (-1)^n \iff 10^n -(-1)^n \iff 11|(10^n - (-1)^n$ and $10 \equiv -1 \implies 10^n \equiv (-1)^n$ is a "one line proof".  If an OP didn't see this right away, I wan't to explain why $a \equiv b \pmod k \implies a^n \equiv b^n$.  And it is because  if $a = b + jk$ for some $j$ then $a^n = (b + jk)^n = b^n + ......$.  Easy, peasy.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$10\equiv -1 \mod 11$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
Note that
$$
x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dotsb+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})
$$

Comment: Thats Newton`s Binom. How it helps?

Comment: Let $x = 10$ and $y = (-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in mod $(11)$ we have $$ 10\equiv (-1)$$

Thus $$ (10)^n -(-1)^n \equiv 0 \mod (11)$$

Comment: Thanks, I agree with the first your line. but the step to second line - i don`t understand

Comment: Thank you for your attention and understanding